# HTML5 <video> tag in Chrome doesn't work

Tags: html, google-chrome, video

I have noticed a strange problem with the HTML5 `<video/>` tag in Chrome.

Using this, it works fine:

```
<video poster="023.png" autoplay controls>
<source src="todojunto.mp4" type="video/mp4"  />
</video>
```

This only plays the sound, no video:

```
<video poster="023.png" autoplay >
<source src="todojunto.mp4" type="video/mp4"  />
</video>
```

If I remove the `poster` attribute, it works again.

All other browsers (even IE9...!) works perfectly, and I can't seem to find the reason.

Any ideas/help?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try with width and height ?

Comment: the same result. it doesn't work

Comment: No extension ? No error in the console ? What do you see in "Elements" regarding position and dimensions of the video object ?

Comment: No error in the console. In "Elements", "Computed Style" shows this: display: inline;
height: 480px;
width: 320px;

I am sure that it is writed correctly because the same document works in the rest of the browsers

Comment: Same issue here ... however, on other occasions the poster attribute doesnt affect playback on chrome ...

Answer (score 9):

Video tag's attributes should be specified for strict standard implementation:

```
<video poster="023.png" autoplay="autoplay" controls="controls">
    <source src="todojunto.mp4" type="video/mp4"  />
</video>
```

If this doesn't work, there is something changed in your browser's preferences

Comment: controls is just what I don't want

Comment: If I remove controls, I can see video but without beeing able to stop it or to seek to another position, may be it's really something with your browser's preferences

Comment: The preferences are the same since the installation. I don´t change them

Comment: what changed in preferences? My preferences seem standard concerning video, but mpt4 does not play. The answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/10997900/801203 seem more appropriate (chrome abandoned mp4)

Comment: Explicitly setting `controls` worked for me, even though I set it to "false".

Answer (score 5):

I'm surprised your video even shows up.  Chrome stopped supporting mp4.  You should use a .webm file when working with Chrome for html5 videos.

Comment: Do you have any references about this ?

Answer (score 4):

> You need to use `muted=""`; it does work for video

```html
<div class="wrap">
 <video width="auto" height="400px" autoplay="" loop="" muted="">
       <source src="Video.mp4"  type="video/mp4">
    <source src="Video.ogg" type="video/ogg">
 </video>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same error.
I fixed it by adding the preload="auto" tag.

```
<video autoplay loop preload="auto" poster="023.png">
    <source src="todojunto.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Don't know if this will work for you, and it's been some time since you asked the question. But maybe this will help someone in the future!

Answer (score 0):

I just converted it to ogv and works well in all browsers. I had problem with firefox but no issues anymore. It was also showing a gray background but now, now anymore. here is my code: you can see it in eargo.com/products

```
<video class="" style="" autoplay loop>
            <source class="" src="video.ogv" >
            <source class="" src="video.mov" >
            <source class="" src="video.mp4" >
</video>
```

you may see it after 5-7-2015.