# Random Video not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, video

I use this code to display a random movie on my page.

It works perfectly in Firefox.

**But in Google Chrome it's not working.**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        var randomVid;
            randomVid = function() {
              var mp4, randomMp4SrcList, randomWebMSrcList, srcMp4, srcWebM, webM;
        randomMp4SrcList = [
            "files/random_movies/video1.mp4", 
            "files/random_movies/video2.mp4", 
            "files/random_movies/video3.mp4",
            "files/random_movies/video4.mp4",
            "files/random_movies/video5.mp4",
            "files/random_movies/video6.mp4",
        ];

              randomWebMSrcList = [
            "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/nytimesvideos/bokeh1.webm", 
            "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/nytimesvideos/bokeh2.webm"];

              mp4 = randomMp4SrcList[Math.floor(Math.random() * randomMp4SrcList.length)];
              webM = randomWebMSrcList[Math.floor(Math.random() * randomWebMSrcList.length)];
              srcMp4 = document.querySelectorAll("#bgvideo > source")[0];
              srcWebM = document.querySelectorAll("#bgvideo > source")[1];
              srcMp4.src=mp4;
              srcWebM.src=webM;
              return;
            };
    </script>
```

---

```
        <div class="background-video-holder">
            <video id="bgvideo" class="background-video hidden-xs" preload="auto" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop">
                <source src=" " type="video/mp4">
                    <source src=" " type="video/webm">
                        <script>
                            randomVid();
                        </script>
            </video>
```

**Any ideas?**

What do I have to change to see a random video in any browsers?

Comment: Rather than using indexes 0 and 1 from `document.querySelectorAll`, you could use `document.querySelector` with the selectors `"#bgvideo > source[type=video/mp4]"` and`"#bgvideo > source[type=video/webm]"` to avoid any confusion if ever their order were to change in the document.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'm getting an access denied on the webm video links
"https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/nytimesvideos/bokeh1.webm"

But other than that, the code is working in Chrome for me.
I did use my own mp4. and it should be encoded with AVC(H264) for video and AAC for audio.
I've tried MPEG4(DivX) for video, but that resulted in sound only.

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats) Chrome should support mp4, but I've found some other sources ([s1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14359487/html5-video-tag-not-working-in-chrome), [s2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757347/html5-video-tag-in-chrome-doesnt-work)) that contradict this. It probably depends on which version of your Chrome.

I then tested a webM video and that works fine too.

So, if mp4 doesn't work in your chrome, and the webM url's get an access denied, then there is no video.

Answer (score 0):

Hy Demian,

Thanks for the Infos. I have to delete this Links ("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/nytimesvideos/bokeh1.webm")

MP4 is working now.

The Video will works only once. If i change the Site with a "Navbar" and go back the Video is not showing. I have to reload the Browser (but only into Google Chrom)

Any Idea?

Thanks a lot.
Regards

Comment: Hi Reto, welcome to stackoverflow. this is a Q&A site, and not a forum. So a followup question like you did here doesn't work really well in this format.  It's better if you ask a new question with the new data and refer to it from this question. Good luck!